# barba js - как сделать наложение переходов

Tags: javascript, transition

Как реализовать наложение переходов в плагине `barba.s`? В примерах на оф сайте, только когда один исчезает, а второй проявляется, а мне нужно что то типа один перекрывает другого.

Вообще не понимаю почитав мануал на оф сайте

> UPD: плагин `barba` используется для `ajax` переходов на сайте, чтобы страницы сменялись с какой-либо анимацей. На оф сайте описан пример анимации перехода, когда старая страница затухает, а новая проявляется, эти две фазы четко разделены, то есть заканчивается первая - начинается вторая. Мне же нужна накладка действий, например есть разделение экрана на пополам, и нужно при переходе, чтобы поверх старой страницы, схлапывалась новая(то есть две части, одна слева одна справа из-за пределов экрана двигались к центру.).

пример с проявлением с офф сайта:

```js
var FadeTransition = Barba.BaseTransition.extend({
  start: function() {
    /**
     * This function is automatically called as soon the Transition starts
     * this.newContainerLoading is a Promise for the loading of the new container
     * (Barba.js also comes with an handy Promise polyfill!)
     */

    // As soon the loading is finished and the old page is faded out, let's fade the new page
    Promise
      .all([this.newContainerLoading, this.fadeOut()])
      .then(this.fadeIn.bind(this));
  },

  fadeOut: function() {
    /**
     * this.oldContainer is the HTMLElement of the old Container
     */

    return $(this.oldContainer).animate({ opacity: 0 }).promise();
  },

  fadeIn: function() {
    /**
     * this.newContainer is the HTMLElement of the new Container
     * At this stage newContainer is on the DOM (inside our #barba-container and with visibility: hidden)
     * Please note, newContainer is available just after newContainerLoading is resolved!
     */

    var _this = this;
    var $el = $(this.newContainer);

    $(this.oldContainer).hide();

    $el.css({
      visibility : 'visible',
      opacity : 0
    });

    $el.animate({ opacity: 1 }, 400, function() {
      /**
       * Do not forget to call .done() as soon your transition is finished!
       * .done() will automatically remove from the DOM the old Container
       */

      _this.done();
    });
  }
});

/**
 * Next step, you have to tell Barba to use the new Transition
 */

Barba.Pjax.getTransition = function() {
  /**
   * Here you can use your own logic!
   * For example you can use different Transition based on the current page or link...
   */

  return FadeTransition;
};
```

Comment: советую, дополнить вопрос, конкретнее изложить суть проблемы, и не плохо было бы увитеть визуально, чего вы хотите...

Comment: добавил описание к посту